# Java Spring Null Pointer Exception when saving ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Trying to save an object of type "Salary" which has ManyToOne relationships with "Role", "City", "SalarySite". It appears to be printing correctly with all the expected data but saving fails. Other similar questions all seem to be missing "@Autowired" but it is present in mine.

The "Dataloader" class, runs a "GoogleSearchScraper" class where we see the error.

**City**

```
package fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.city;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.Salary;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String currency;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="city", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Salary> salaries;

    protected City(){}

    public City(String name, String country, String currency){
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getName(){ return this.name; }

    public String getCountry(){ return this.country; }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("City[id=%d, name='%s', country = '%s', currency= '%s']",
                id, name, country, currency);
    }

}
```

**City Repository**

```
package fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.city;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Long> {

}
```

**Role**

```
package fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.role;

import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.Salary;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String seniority;
    private String roleName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Salary> salaries;



    protected Role(){}

    public Role(String seniority,String roleName){
        this.seniority = seniority;
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public String getSeniorityAndRole(){
        if (this.seniority != ""){
            return String.format("%s %s", this.seniority, this.roleName);
        } else{
            return roleName;
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("id=%d, %s %s", id, seniority, roleName);
    }


}
```

**Role Repository**

```
package fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.role;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Long> {

}
```

**SalarySite**

```
package fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.salarysite;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class SalarySite {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String searchUrl;
    private String salaryElementClass;

    protected SalarySite(){}

    public SalarySite(String name, String searchUrl, String salaryElementClass){
        this.name = name;
        this.searchUrl = searchUrl;
        this.salaryElementClass = salaryElementClass;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s %s %s", name, searchUrl, salaryElementClass);
    }

    public String getSearchUrl(){
        return searchUrl;
    }

    public String getSalaryElementClass(){
        return salaryElementClass;
    }
}
```

**SalarySiteRepo**

```
package fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.salarysite;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface SalarySiteRepository extends CrudRepository<SalarySite, Long> {

}
```

**Salary**

```
package fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary;

import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.city.City;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.role.Role;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.salarysite.SalarySite;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Salary {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private int compensation;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "site_id")
    private SalarySite site;

    protected Salary(){}

    public Salary(int compensation, Role role, City city,  SalarySite site){
        this.compensation = compensation;
        this.role = role;
        this.city = city;
        this.site = site;
    }

    public int getCompensation(){
        return this.compensation;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city.getName();
    }

    public String getSeniorityAndRoleName(){
        return role.getSeniorityAndRole();
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Salary[id=%d, compensation=%d, city='%s', role='%s'",
                        id, compensation, city, role);
    }

}
```

**Salary Repository**

```
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.city.City;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.role.Role;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.salarysite.SalarySite;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface SalaryRepository extends CrudRepository<Salary, Long> {
    //List<Salary> findByLocation(String location);

    Salary findById(long id);

    boolean existsBySiteAndCityAndRole(SalarySite salarySite, City city, Role role);
}
```

**Dataloader**

```
package fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.service;

import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.city.City;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.city.CityRepository;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.role.RoleRepository;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.Salary;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.SalaryRepository;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.salarysite.SalarySite;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.role.Role;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.salarysite.SalarySiteRepository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;




@Component
@Slf4j
public class DataLoader {

    @Autowired
    private SalaryRepository salaryRepository;
    @Autowired
    private SalarySiteRepository siteRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CityRepository cityRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;



    @PostConstruct
    public void process() {
        List<SalarySite> salarySiteList = new ArrayList<>();
        siteRepository.findAll().forEach(salarySiteList::add);

        List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<>();
        roleRepository.findAll().forEach(roleList::add);

        List<City> cityList = new ArrayList();
        cityRepository.findAll().forEach(cityList::add);

        List<Salary> salaryList = new ArrayList<>();
        salaryRepository.findAll().forEach(salaryList::add);



        log.info("Entering Loop");
        log.info("--------------------");
        int numberOfSalaries = salaryList.size();
        int numberOfRoles = roleList.size();
        int numberOfSites = salarySiteList.size();
        int numberOfCities = cityList.size();

        log.info(String.format("salary list %d", numberOfSalaries));
        log.info(String.format("role list %d", numberOfRoles));
        log.info(String.format("site list %d", numberOfSites));
        log.info(String.format("city list %d", numberOfCities));

        for (SalarySite salarySite : salarySiteList){
           for (City city: cityList){
                for (Role role: roleList){
                    boolean foundSalary = salaryRepository.existsBySiteAndCityAndRole(salarySite, city, role);
                    if (foundSalary == true) {
                        log.debug("Found");
                    } else {
                        log.debug("Not Found, Scraping");
                        String roleTitle = role.getSeniorityAndRole();
                        String cityName = city.getName();
                        String searchUrl = salarySite.getSearchUrl();
                        String salaryElementClass = salarySite.getSalaryElementClass();
                        ScraperService siteScraper = new GoogleSearchScraper(role, city, salarySite);
                        siteScraper.executeScrape();
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

**Google Search Scraper**

```
package fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.service;

import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.city.City;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.role.Role;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.Salary;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.SalaryRepository;
import fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.salarysite.SalarySite;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class GoogleSearchScraper implements ScraperService {
    private Role role;
    private City city;
    private SalarySite site;

    private String webPageUrl;
    private int compensation;

    @Autowired
    SalaryRepository salaryRepo;

    public GoogleSearchScraper(){}

    public GoogleSearchScraper(Role role, City city, SalarySite site){
        this.role = role;
        this.city = city;
        this.site = site;
    }

    @Override
    public void executeScrape(){
        int statusCodeFetchUrl = fetchWebpageUrl();
        log.info(String.format("fetchWebPageUrl for %s : %d", toString(), statusCodeFetchUrl));
        int parsePageStatusCode = parsePageForSalary();
        log.info(String.format("parseUrl for salary %s : %d", toString(), parsePageStatusCode));
        saveSalary();
    }

    @Override
    public int fetchWebpageUrl(){
        String title = role.getSeniorityAndRole();
        title = title.replace(" ", "+");
        String searchUrl = site.getSearchUrl();
        String cityName = city.getName();;
        String fullUrl = String.format("%s%s+%s", searchUrl, title, cityName);
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(fullUrl))
                .GET()
                .build();
        int statusCode = 0;
        try{
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
                    HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            statusCode = response.statusCode();
            String jsonResultLink = new JSONObject(response.body())
                    .getJSONArray("items")
                    .getJSONObject(0)
                    .getString("link");
            log.info(city + " " + role + " " + jsonResultLink);
            this.webPageUrl = jsonResultLink;

            return statusCode;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
            return statusCode;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int parsePageForSalary() {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.ALWAYS)
                .build();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(this.webPageUrl))
                .GET()
                .build();
        int statusCode = 0;
        try{
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
                    HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            statusCode = response.statusCode();
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response.body());
            Element salaryElement = doc.getElementsByClass(site.getSalaryElementClass()).first();
            String salaryText = salaryElement.text();
            char[] salaryChars = salaryText.toCharArray();
            String nonDigitCharacters = "";
            for (char c: salaryChars){
                if (!Character.isDigit(c)){
                    salaryText = salaryText.replace(Character.toString(c),"");
                    nonDigitCharacters += c;
                }
            }
            log.info(this.toString() + " removed " + nonDigitCharacters + " from salary " + salaryText);
            this.compensation = Integer.parseInt(salaryText);
            return statusCode;
        } catch (Exception e){
            log.error(e.toString());
            return statusCode;
        }
    }

    public void saveSalary(){
        Salary scrapedSalary = new Salary(this.compensation, this.role, this.city, this.site);
        log.info("saving " + scrapedSalary.toString());
        salaryRepo.save(scrapedSalary);
    }

    @Override
    public String getWebPageUrl() {
        return webPageUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSalary() {
        if (this.compensation == 0){
            parsePageForSalary();
            return this.compensation;
        }
        return this.compensation;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Scraper %s, %s, %s", role.getSeniorityAndRole(),
                city.getName(), site.getName());
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
2022-01-23 10:53:54.194  INFO 34291 --- [           main] f.i.s.s.service.GoogleSearchScraper      : saving Salary[id=0, compensation=36149, city='City[id=1, name='Dublin', country = 'Ireland', currency= 'EUR']', role='id=1, Junior Software Developer'
2022-01-23 10:53:54.194  WARN 34291 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
2022-01-23 10:53:54.195  INFO 34291 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-01-23 10:53:54.196  INFO 34291 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-01-23 10:53:54.210  INFO 34291 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-01-23 10:53:54.211  INFO 34291 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-01-23 10:53:54.222  INFO 34291 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-01-23 10:53:54.237 ERROR 34291 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.SalaryTaxSpendApplication.main(SalaryTaxSpendApplication.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.service.GoogleSearchScraper.saveSalary(GoogleSearchScraper.java:119) ~[classes/:na]
    at fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.service.GoogleSearchScraper.executeScrape(GoogleSearchScraper.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at fyi.incomeoutcome.salarytaxspend.salary.service.DataLoader.process(DataLoader.java:78) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating an instance of GoogleSearchScraper yourself, fields will not be autowired by Spring. Therefore, salaryRepository is null.
You could inject the SalaryRepository instance yourself upon creation of GoogleSearchScraper like this:

```
ScraperService siteScraper = new GoogleSearchScraper(role, city, salarySite, salaryRepo);
siteScraper.executeScrape();
```

Of course you need to add SalaryRepository to the constructor parameter list and assign it.
Consider removing `@Component` from GoogleSearchScraper if you want to create instances yourself. You only need it when instances shall be managed by Spring.